# Too many lines output from gridsearch when njobs large than 1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cloudera, grid-search

I use the following code to do the gridsearch, set the njobs=crossvalidation fold, but I got many lines likes the below:

```
GridSearchCV(estimator = est,
                                cv = crossval_n,
                                n_jobs = crossval_n,
                                param_grid = param_grid,
                                scoring = grid_score,
                                verbose = 1000)
```

the info is like this:

```
Pickling array (shape=(2,), dtype=object).
Pickling array (shape=(7,), dtype=object).
Pickling array (shape=(5,), dtype=object).
Pickling array (shape=(5,), dtype=object).
Pickling array (shape=(2,), dtype=object).
Memmaping (shape=(300000,), dtype=float64) to old file /dev/shm/joblib_memmaping_pool_31858_140577309572624/31858-140577424627920-252eb20f1c96190cb0ef65643005ff1e.pkl
Memmaping (shape=(199999,), dtype=int64) to old file /dev/shm/joblib_memmaping_pool_31858_140577309572624/31858-140577424627920-e2ad805d63b492d1bda22f6ecd785fa9.pkl
Pickling array (shape=(100001,), dtype=int64).
[CV]  n_estimators=25, loss=deviance, learning_rate=0.05, max_depth=3, score=0.663848252373, total= 4.5min
[CV] n_estimators=100, loss=deviance, learning_rate=0.05, max_depth=3 
[Parallel(n_jobs=3)]: Done   1 tasks      | elapsed:  4.9min
Pickling array (shape=(3376,), dtype=object).
Memmaping (shape=(73, 300000), dtype=float64) to old file /dev/shm/joblib_memmaping_pool_31858_140577309572624/31858-140577424627920-2a1a398dde29f0da54a999a91072b77b.pkl
Memmaping (shape=(1, 300000), dtype=int64) to old file /dev/shm/joblib_memmaping_pool_31858_140577309572624/31858-140577424627920-108448b3fbe2af627fc26e0b965874b9.pkl
Memmaping (shape=(62, 300000), dtype=float64) to old file /dev/shm/joblib_memmaping_pool_31858_140577309572624/31858-140577424627920-32d40c577c413ff0ea04ade1cc62a62e.pkl
```

Not sure 
1) what's the info about? 
2) is there any error if I got this information?
3) if it is not error message, how to disable print it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `verbose` param you are using.

> ```
> verbose : integer
>
>     Controls the verbosity: the higher, the more messages.
> ```

You are using `verbose=1000`, so you are getting the progress of the tuning process in the output.

Change `verbose=0` to disable it.